# Position vs displacement vector

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, euclidean-geometry

Is there a practical difference between position and displacement vectors when performing common geometric operations on them?

For example, I'm thinking about affine transformations, commonly used in computer graphics, where position and direction vectors need to be handled differently, etc...

Comment: See "https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-position-vector-and-a-displacement-vector"

Comment: You seem to have answered "yes" to your own question. Was there some additional detail or understanding you wanted?

Comment: @DavidK Read carefully, in my example I refer to direction vectors, which are another kind of vectors, different from both position and displacement vectors.